# Accurate traffic information for past dates: Traffic of HERE Route API calls changes for same query over time?

Tags: routes, here-api

I have been working with the HERE API Isoline Route API V7. Especially interesting is the feature of getting accurate travel time estimates for different time of days.

I now realized, that querying for past dates does not always yield the same result.
So, e.g. a query I did yesterday resulted in a travel time of 1134 seconds. Today, for the same trip, day and start time I get 982 seconds.
It's hard to provide a reproducible example here, so I added two screenshots of the query from yesterday and today.

[image]

[image]

Now I was wondering, does the way traffic computed by HERE include CURRENT traffic information for queries in the past? Since there has been a lockdown since November here in Germany, is the query for August also affected by the reduced traffic AFTER August?

I am actually looking for accurate PRE-Corona traffic information and now realized that queries for January and February 2020 do not seem to properly reflect the Pre-Corona traffic pattern. Also, queries I did a few weeks ago seem to have MORE traffic time included than the same queries executed today.

I did not find any further information on how past traffic is defined, except this:

> Traffic speed and incidents are taken into account when calculating the route, where applicable (note that in case of a past departure time the historical traffic is limited to one year)

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-get-route.html#resource-get-route

Does anyone know more about this?

And if averaged traffic information AFTER the queried date is used for queries on past dates, is there a way to get accurate PRE-Corona traffic times? (maybe also sth else than HERE)?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use the latest version of the API, since v7 is now in maintenance (that means it still works but it is deprecated). Check this out https://developer.here.com/documentation/isoline-routing-api/8.4.0/migration_guide/index.html